# Beamer pdf play video WITHOUT sound

Tags: beamer, graphics, movie15

My `beamer` pdf plays the video but there is no audio! My code is given below -

```
\documentclass[graphics]{beamer}
 \usepackage{movie15}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{This is a movie showing a rotating wave}
 \begin{picture}(320,300)
 \put(0,80){\includemovie[poster, text={\small(Loading sample.swf)}]{9cm}{6cm}{sample.swf}}
 \put(90,260){Rotating sine}
 \end{picture}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Package `movie15` is outdated, use `media9` instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a now-defunct package. At the present time, `media9` should be used instead.